# iOS - swift 3 - heatmap

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, heatmap

i am using this project to generate my heatmap:

```
https://github.com/dataminr/DTMHeatmap
```

I integrated the code as stated in:

```
https://github.com/dataminr/DTMHeatmap/issues/1
```

from @johndpope:

```
https://github.com/johndpope/TranSafe
```

First, it is compiled successfully, but when i use the "readData" like this:

```
readData([[52.517138, 13.401489], [52.517137, 13.401488], [52.517136, 13.401487]])
```

i get the

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=blabla) error
```

here is the method:

```
func readData(_ array: [[Double]]){
    self.heatmap = DTMHeatmap()
    var dict = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>();
    for entry in array{

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: entry[1], longitude: entry[0]);

        let mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate)

        let type = NSValue(mkCoordinate: coordinate).objCType // <- THIS IS IT

        let value = NSValue(bytes: Unmanaged.passUnretained(mapPoint as AnyObject).toOpaque(), objCType: type);
        dict[value] = 1 as AnyObject?;

    }
    self.heatmap.setData(dict as [AnyHashable: Any]);
    self.mapView.add(self.heatmap)
}

func MKMapPointForCoordinate(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MKMapPoint {

    return MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);

}

// etc ...
```

I have really no idea what i have done wrong, anybody could help me with this issue?

Comment: `coordinate` looks as expected?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454230/convert-mkmappoint-to-nsvalue-in-swift

Comment: coordinate looks as expected?

Comment: so what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can read from the original code of `DTMHeatmap`, the keys for the dictionary passed for `setData` need to be `NSValue`s containing `MKMapPoint`. And the code you have shown is not a proper code to make such `NSValue`s. (I really doubt the original Swift 2 code you have found would actually work..., `MKMapView` cannot be bridged to Objective-C object in Swift 2, so `mapPoint as! AnyObject` should always fail.)

The `readData` method should be something like this:

```
func readData(_ array: [[Double]]){
    self.heatmap = DTMHeatmap()
    var dict: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]
    for entry in array{

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: entry[1], longitude: entry[0]);

        var mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate)

        //Creating `objCType` manually is not recommended, but Swift does not have `@encoding()`...
        let type = "{MKMapPoint=dd}"

        let value = NSValue(bytes: &mapPoint, objCType: type)
        dict[value] = 1

    }
    self.heatmap.setData(dict)
    self.mapView.add(self.heatmap)
}
```

(I haven't checked with the actual `DTMHeatmap`, so you may need some more fixes.)

Comment: thanks for participating... i replaced the code, but its still not drawing the map.. i can not even guess what is wrong with this implementation.. moreover its strange, that ios/swift does not provide a basic heatmap library?

Comment: @Creativecrypter, one thing I can advise to you is that you should start with actually working sample code. You should not rely on some code which cannot construct even a simple `NSValue`...

Comment: ye but to be honest, its the only resource about "heatmaps on ios", so there are no other possibilities.. what do you think?

Comment: @Creativecrypter, I can fix some small part of code if there is enough information, but cannot do anything with just not-working example shown. If you could find a working example and only some parts of it were hard to port or had a few flaws, I or many other readers would help you. Till then you might need to find out what part is not working well, by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Very performant heatmap library. I managed to get this working and it renders nicely. I am adding this answer because it also includes the rendererFor overlay delegate function needed to work.

```
class HeatmapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var heatmap: DTMHeatmap? = nil
var diffHeatmap: DTMDiffHeatmap? = nil
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var ret: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]

    for location in locations {
        var mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location.coordinate)
        let mapPointValue = NSValue(bytes: &mapPoint, objCType: "{MKMapPoint=dd}")

        ret[mapPointValue] = 10.0 // weight
     }

     self.heatmap = DTMHeatmap()
     self.heatmap?.setData(ret)

     self.mapView.delegate = self; // Important
     self.mapView.add(self.heatmap!)   
  }
}
```

This part is very important and for this to work you need to set the mapView's delegate to self.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    return DTMHeatmapRenderer(overlay: overlay)
}
```